# Wrap divs with same classes (and multiple classes) in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are a lot of similar questions, but none like this one.
I have the following html:

```
<div class="view-content">

    <div class="section section_2">content</div>
    <div class="section section_2">content</div>
    <div class="section section_1">content</div>
    <div class="section section_4">content</div>
    <div class="section section_4">content</div>

</div>
```

Where all the divs share *.section* but the other class is dynamic generated depending of a database ID.

How Can I wrap the divs with same class inside another div If I don't know the dynamic class?

For example on the following [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzgn7ef7/1/) If I remove the .section class it will wrapp ok but my divs have multiples classes and only one is shared.

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not exactly understanding what you're trying to do. Could you post HTML of what you want the end result to be?

Actually, I think I understand. You want to wrap section 4 together in one div?

Comment: You only wrap divs in a new div if the common class exists between consecutive divs correct?

Comment: When you control the html creation you should consider adding another (data) attribute to store the section_id for your grouping task. Would be cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var classes = {};
$(".view-content > div").each(function() {
    classes[$(this).attr("class")] = true; // "section section_2"
});
for (singleClass in classes) {
    // No elements will be returned here
    $("." + singleClass).wrapAll('<div class="column" />');
}
```

Your code was close, but the problem is the string returns `"section section1"` or something thereof, so when you try to select by that, you're essentially doing `$('.section section1')` which isn't going to match anything. If you want to group by the second argument in the class structure, you can split the class string, and grab the second one.

```
var classes = {};
$(".view-content > div").each(function() {
    var temp = $(this).attr("class").split(' ');
    if (temp[1]) {
        classes[temp[1]] = true;
    }
});
for (singleClass in classes) {
    $("." + singleClass).wrapAll('<div class="column" />');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vzgn7ef7/2/

Ninja edit. Few things I'd like to point out. This is going to make your code dependent on the fact that there's always going to be at least two classes, and you want the second one. If that changes, this breaks.

Comment: Thanks it worked, on my code the first class is the one I use, so I changed temp[1] to temp [0] and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Providing that your `section-n's` are always sequential, you can simplify it to a single `for` loop:

```
var $sections = $('div.section'),
    sCount = $sections.length;

for (var i = 0; i < sCount; ) {  

    var sClass = $sections[i].className.match(/section_\d+/).shift(),
        $section = $('.' + sClass);

    i = $section.wrapAll('<div>').filter(':last').index('div.section') + 1;
}
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzgn7ef7/7/)

Comment: For some reason this crashed my browser. My divs are sequential so im not sure why. On the jsfiddle if i change to non sequential it also crash the browser so i suspect some html of my real code is affecting it.