# addClass as first in element instead of last

Tags: jquery

I am having a `<li>` like this:

```
<li class="product type-product status-publish"></li>
```

I am adding a class with this code:

```
$("li").addClass("firstclass");
```

The output of it is like this:

```
<li class="product type-product status-publish firstclass"></li>
```

Is it possible to force the class to be in first of all the classes so the output is gonna be like:

```
<li class="firstclass product type-product status-publish"></li>
```

Hope you guys can help!

Comment: It makes absolutely no difference whatsoever what order your classes are listed in

Comment: To add to the above, I presume you want to do this because the styling rules from `firstclass` are not being applied? If so, research rule specificity in CSS

Comment: If this is related to css rule conflicts then you should make your css selectors more specific for these classes

Comment: Yes it does matter because I am using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367868/wrap-divs-with-same-classes-and-multiple-classes-in-jquery. So I want `temp` always to be `0`

Answer (score -4):

You can, but its tedious and probably wont make a practical difference. You'll have to disable all the other classes, add the first one, and then add the others back, e.g.

```
$("li").toggleClass("product");
$("li").toggleClass("type-product");
$("li").toggleClass("type-product");
$("li").toggleClass("status-publish");
$("li").addClass("firstclass");
$("li").toggleClass("product");
$("li").toggleClass("type-product");
$("li").toggleClass("type-product");
$("li").toggleClass("status-publish");
```